# Bajaj Pulsar 150 2012 model engine sound

Tags: motorcycle, noise, bajaj, pulsar

I have Bajaj Pulsar 150 2012 model and has run 51500KM as of now. Just 10/15 days back bike service is done, prior to that only had changed the engine oil. Since 2 days on accelerating a crackling sound (similar to KTM Duke 200 engine sound) is coming out along with normal Pulsar 150 engine sound (buzzy one, normal one). the crackling sound is more. Feels like something has broken inside n that is making this sound. Please suggest.

I took it to nearby service center n they are saying should get engine bore and would cost upto 10K. I only ride in city limits havent used it roughly.. is it bore necessary at 51500KM? Please clarify my doubts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The only service at 51500 km? that seems odd - my car has 20000km service intervals - if it has missed services, then yes they may be right and it needs boring / honing and a new set of rings & piston...

Comment: No not one service at 51500km :D... Have done bike service 3 months once till date.. and engine oil every 4000KM once (Using Shell engine oil)..